# Where to find a list of purchased books in the Amazon Kindle app for iPad?

Tags: ipados, ebook, kindle

In the current version of the Kindle app for iPad OS 13, I cannot find any list of books I have previously purchased.

I found a hamburger menu item for “Lists”, but that shows a blank page.

Where should I be looking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current latest version of the Kindle app running on iPadOS 13 is Version 6.28. Follow these steps to see the list of all your purchased books:

1. First of all, make sure you are logged into the Kindle app with the correct account. To ensure, tap on the **More** button shown at the bottom toolbar, and then tap on the **Settings** item.

   [image]

   Check for the logged in account under **Registration**.

   [image]
2. Once confirmed, Tap on the (X) button shown at top right to dismiss the Settings screen. Now in the bottom toolbar, tap on the Library button to navigate to the Library screen.
3. Once on the Library screen, in the toolbar shown under the search bar at the top of the screen, tap on **All** to show all the books, samples and documents associated with your account. Selecting **Downloaded** would only show the books, samples and documents downloaded locally, and it would show a blank page if you have not downloaded or synced any content to your iPad.

   [image]

   Tap on the Filter button shown towards the top left of the screen (under the bell icon), to filter the listing to show just the purchased books by tapping on the **Books** item.

   [image]

The same steps can be followed to access the list of purchased books in the iPhone app.